# XSLT value select based on multiple tags and it's values

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to know how to get value from below xml. I tried couple of different approaches and it seems I cannot find the correct solution.

```
<a>
    <aid>ok</aid>
    <b>
        <bid>ok</bid>
        <c>
            <cid>ok</cid>
            <d>
                <dValue>goal</dValue>
            </d>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

Condition must meet below criteria:

- if `<a><aid>` value is ok
- if `<a><b><bid>` value is ok
- if `<a><b><c><cid>` value is ok
- then I need value of `<a><b><c><d><dValue>`

Any help would be much appreciated as I've spent couple of hours on this already :) Oh, I'm using xslt 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="a[aid='ok']/b[bid='ok']/c[cid='ok']/d/dValue"/>
```

Comment: Worked in first try. I wasn't far but I made mistake in brackets so it didn't find anything in my attempts. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**A more general task**:

In case the names of the elements don't matter and the depth of the path (number of nested elements) can be any , but the children have as name  the name of the parent appended with "id", then this XPath 2.0 expression produses the wanted result in all such cases, including the current one:

```
//dValue[every $anc in ../ancestor::* 
          satisfies $anc/*[name() eq concat($anc/name(), 'id')]/string() eq 'ok' ]/string()
```

**XSLT 2.0 verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
    "//dValue[every $anc in ../ancestor::* 
       satisfies $anc/*[name() eq concat($anc/name(), 'id')]/string() eq 'ok' ]/string()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<a>
    <aid>ok</aid>
    <b>
        <bid>ok</bid>
        <c>
            <cid>ok</cid>
            <d>
                <dValue>goal</dValue>
            </d>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

**it evaluates the expression and outputs the result of this evaluation**:

```
goal
```

**Applying the same transformation on this XML document**:

```
<x>
    <xid>ok</xid>
    <y>
        <yid>ok</yid>
        <z>
            <zid>ok</zid>
            <t>
                <dValue>goal2</dValue>
            </t>
        </z>
    </y>
</x>
```

**again produces the wanted correct result**:

```
goal2
```

Comment: Even thou it is a good solution, it seems overkill in my case. But it's noted if I'll need it in the future, thanks.

Comment: @Matjaz, I wrote this, because you wanted XPath 2.0 solutions :)